# Replace multiple string in file with values from Dictionary using Python

Tags: python

I have a file with content as below,I would like to replace feed-1/feed-2... with respective key-values from dictionary in file. Using fileread I am trying to replace but its replacing value multiple times.

```
No.of documents  in collection{col_id="feed-2"} 620
No.of documents  in collection{col_id="feed-3"} 630
No.of documents  in collection{col_id="feed-4"} 650
No.of documents  in collection{col_id="feed-5"} 670
```

I have a dictionary with content as below.

```
dict={'feed-1': 'important', 'feed-2': 'low', 'feed-3': 'critical', 'feed-4':'medium', 'feed-5':'low'}
```

Comment: if this is a problem with file i/o, let's see what code you were using to read and write the changes out to a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need 2 calls to open the file for reading and writing as @RishabhHardas did. You can do it with one statement: using `r+` flag and the combination of `seek(0)` and `truncate()` to delete the old content of the file, for example:

```py
d={'feed-1': 'important', 'feed-2': 'low', 'feed-3': 'critical', 'feed-4':'medium', 'feed-5':'low'}

with open('text.txt', 'r+') as file:
    content = file.read()
    for k, v in d.items():
        content = content.replace(k, v)
    file.seek(0)
    file.truncate()
    file.write(content)
```

Outputs:

```
No.of documents  in collection{col_id="low"} 620
No.of documents  in collection{col_id="critical"} 630
No.of documents  in collection{col_id="medium"} 650
No.of documents  in collection{col_id="low"} 670
```

Also you shouldn't use `dict` as a variable name, is a reserved python keyword.

Comment: everything is working as expected but after running above script I am seeing output as below:

No.of documents  in collection{col_id="low"} 620
No.of documents  in collection{col_id="critical"} 630
No.of documents  in collection{col_id="medium"} 650
No.of documents  in collection{col_id="low"} 670
{col_id="feed-5"}

I am not sure why the last-line is staying so.

Comment: @balav, it's my mistake, i missed to call `file.truncate()` so if the new content of the file is shorter than the old one, at the end of the file is going to show portions of the old file. That is fixed now, see the update.

Comment: Super thanks marcos, I just figured it online..Anyway much thanks for your correction

Answer (score 2):

This one-liner should do it.

```
re.sub(rf"({'|'.join(dict.keys())})", lambda m: rf"{dict[m.group(1)]}", text)
```

Here it is in action:

```
>>> text = """
... No.of documents  in collection{col_id="feed-2"} 620
... No.of documents  in collection{col_id="feed-3"} 630
... No.of documents  in collection{col_id="feed-4"} 650
... No.of documents  in collection{col_id="feed-5"} 670
... """
>>> dict={'feed-1': 'important', 'feed-2': 'low', 'feed-3': 'critical',
...       'feed-4':'medium', 'feed-5':'low'}
>>> 
>>> r =re.sub(f"({'|'.join(dict.keys())})", lambda m: f"{dict[m.group(1)]}", text)
>>> print(r)

No.of documents  in collection{col_id="low"} 620
No.of documents  in collection{col_id="critical"} 630
No.of documents  in collection{col_id="medium"} 650
No.of documents  in collection{col_id="low"} 670

>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the below solution I have taken a.txt as the input file which contains the text given in your question and b.txt is the output file

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

dict={'feed-1': 'important', 'feed-2': 'low', 'feed-3': 'critical', 'feed-4':'medium', 'feed-5':'low'}

fout = open("b.txt", "wt")

with open("a.txt") as fp:
    line = fp.readline()
    while line:
        for k, v in dict.items():
            line = line.replace(k, v)

        print(line)
        fout.write(line)
        line = fp.readline()

fout.close()
```

Contents of b.txt after execution of code are as follows

```
No.of documents  in collection{col_id="low"} 620
No.of documents  in collection{col_id="critical"} 630
No.of documents  in collection{col_id="medium"} 650
No.of documents  in collection{col_id="low"} 670
```